# Basics questions regarding File and I/O System Calls in C (on Linux/UNIX)

Tags: c, linux, unix, system-calls

I'm working on improving my C programming knowledge, but I am having trouble understanding the man pages for the following Unix system calls:

```
open
create
close
unlink
read
write
lseek
```

The man pages for each of these are, for lack of a better term, completely confusing and unintelligible.  For example, here is the **man page for open**:

---

"Given a pathname for a file, open() returns a file descriptor, a small, nonnegative integer for use in subsequent system calls (read(2), write(2), lseek(2), fcntl(2), etc.). The file descriptor returned by a successful call will be the lowest-numbered file descriptor not currently open for the process.
By default, the new file descriptor is set to remain open across an execve(2) (i.e., the FD_CLOEXEC file descriptor flag described in fcntl(2) is initially disabled; the O_CLOEXEC flag, described below, can be used to change this default). The file offset is set to the beginning of the file (see lseek(2)).

A call to open() creates a new open file description, an entry in the system-wide table of open files. This entry records the file offset and the file status flags (modifiable via the fcntl(2) F_SETFL operation). A file descriptor is a reference to one of these entries; this reference is unaffected if pathname is subsequently removed or modified to refer to a different file. The new open file description is initially not shared with any other process, but sharing may arise via fork(2)."

---

I have no idea what this all means.  From my understanding, if open returns a negative integer, an error occurred, and if it returns a positive integer, then that integer can be used in further system calls (???).  That is, unfortunately, basically the extent of my knowledge and what I can attempt to parse from the man page.  I need some help.

What does it mean that it "returns the lowest-numbered file descriptor not currently open for the process"?  What process is it referring to?  Why is it the lowest-numbered file descriptor, and why does this matter/how would I use this?  I hate to sound like an idiot but I honestly have no clue what it's talking about.

Let's take an example.  Let's say I wanted to create a new file in a directory, and open up a file from another directory, and copy the file I opened into the file I created, while checking for errors along the way.  This is my attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int main()
{
  int XYZ = creat("XYZ.doc", 0 );
  if (XYZ < 0)
    printf("file creating error");
  int file = open("/usr/.../xx.xx", 0);
  if(file < 0)
    printf("file opening error");
}
```

**How would I copy the file that I opened into the file that I created?  That should be easy.  But what if I wanted to copy the file that I opened in reverse to the file that I created?  (Maybe that example will illuminate how to use the file offset stuff mentioned in the man page, which I don't currently understand...)**

I would like to edit this post to write a layman's terms description next to each of these system calls, thus creating a good online resource for people to study from.  Also, if anyone has any good references for these system calls in C, that would be much appreciated as well.

Comment: Take a look at [`fprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fprintf.html), the file descriptor is the first argument.

Comment: The first argument to fprintf is a FILE* not a **file descriptor**.

Comment: The `man` pages for your own system and environment  *are* the best references. Possibly you are confusing them with Basic Tutorials (which they are not, and not intended to be).

Comment: So if I don't understand the man pages, then where can I start?  What are the Basic Tutorials you mentioned?  (Not sure if you just mean in general, or if referring to specific ones)

Comment: For the moment, forget about `the lowest numbered`. Remember that open() and creat() return a non-negative integer value, that can be used to addrss that particular file for subsequent operations (read() ... write() , ...) on that file. And finally, you can use the file descriptor to close() the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error checking left out for simplicity sake:

```
char data[1024];     /* size of this chosen more or less on a whim */
ssize_t n;

while ((n = read(file, data, sizeof(data))) > 0) {
    write(XYZ, data, n);
}
close(file);
close(XYZ);
```

Comment: Hey John, just wanted to give a big thanks for this example, as it actually helps more than you might think.  I'm having trouble finding examples for these online, do you know of any good tutorials or readings regarding these?

Comment: @Musicode Here's a couple which seem decent http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/languages/C/teaching_C/  http://alandix.com/academic/tutorials/courses/unixprog.html  http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/CE.html

Comment: You'd be surprised how much an example helped with this code.  I have trouble understanding those man pages at all, I would have to read all of them and be a long time Linux user (I used to be, but it's been over 8 years now).